# Low Quality Posts queue annoying background animation

Tags: feature-request, bug, review-queues, design, low-quality-posts

When reviewing answer posts in the low quality queue I noticed that when I go to the next review it does the jQuery background color animation thing of changing the answer box from orangeish to regular whitish background color.

I just noticed this today. I have no idea if it has always been like this or not. But it started to annoy me today. I mean the review you're doing is always the top one, it doesn't show multiple answers or the other answers to that same question on the page. So why the need for the background animation thing to point it out?

Comment: I have trouble taking this post seriously without an animated gif.